# Calculate time from an array and convert to time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, time, average

I have an array `bed_times` with `Time` instances in UTC format:

```
bed_times = [
  Time.utc(2015, 12, 10,  5, 58, 24),
  Time.utc(2015, 12,  9,  3, 35, 28),
  Time.utc(2015, 12,  8,  6, 32, 26),
  Time.utc(2015, 12,  7,  1, 43, 28),
  Time.utc(2015, 12,  5,  7, 49, 30),
  Time.utc(2015, 12, 04,  7,  2, 30)
]
#=> [2015-12-10 05:58:24 UTC,
#    2015-12-09 03:35:28 UTC,
#    2015-12-08 06:32:26 UTC,
#    2015-12-07 01:43:28 UTC,
#    2015-12-05 07:49:30 UTC,
#    2015-12-04 07:02:30 UTC]
```

I am trying to get the average bedtime, but I'm not getting the correct result

```
ave = Time.at(bed_times.map(&:to_f).inject(:+) / bed_times.size)
```

result is

```
2015-12-07 01:26:57 -0800
```

which is not correct.  Also, I want to then convert the average time to a different time zone

I tried

```
Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
Time.zone.parse(ave.to_s)
2015-12-07 01:26:57 -0800
```

This is not correct either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calculate the **average on the gap from midnight**.

A not elegant (but fast) solution could be:

```
# Keep only time    
bed_times.map! { |bt| Time.parse(bt.split(" ")[1]) }

# calculate the gap from 00:00:00
gap_from_midnight = bed_times.map do |bt|
  if bt > Time.parse("12:00:00")
    gap = (bt.to_f - Time.parse("24:00:00").to_f)
  else
    gap = (bt.to_f - Time.parse("00:00:00").to_f)
  end
  gap.to_i
end

# average in sec
avg_in_sec = gap_from_midnight.inject(:+) / bed_times.size

# average in UTC time zone 
avg = Time.at(avg_in_sec).utc # => 1970-01-01 05:26:57 UTC (result for bed_times array)

# average in PST time zone (see note)
avg_pst = Time.parse(avg.to_s).in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") # => Wed, 31 Dec 1969 21:26:57 PST -08:00 (result for bed_times array)

# Keep only time
avg_pst.strftime("%H:%M:%S") # => "21:26:57" (result for bed_times array)
```

With your `bed_times` array **(with the values as a string)**

```
bed_times = [
  "2015-12-10 05:58:24 UTC",
  "2015-12-09 03:35:28 UTC",
  "2015-12-08 06:32:26 UTC",
  "2015-12-07 01:43:28 UTC",
  "2015-12-05 07:49:30 UTC",
  "2015-12-04 07:02:30 UTC"
]
```

the average is :

- `05:26:57` in UTC zone
- `21:26:57` in PST zone

With another array like this

```
bed_times = [
  "2015-12-10 01:00:00 UTC",
  "2015-12-09 23:00:00 UTC",
  "2015-10-19 18:00:00 UTC",
]
```

the average is:

- `22:00:00` in UTC zone
- `14:00:00` in PST zone

**note:** `.in_time_zone` is a helper from `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`
   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html

Comment: times = bed_times.map! { |bt| Time.parse(bt.split(" ")[1]) }
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `split' for 2015-12-11 05:58:24 -0800:Time

I then tried bt.to_s.split...but it didn't split.

Comment: I thought that was an array of string. [ "2015-12-10 05:58:24 UTC" , "..",]. And If I try to create a Time object from your values I give an error:
 Time.new(2015-12-10 05:58:24 UTC)
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'
Time.new(2015-12-10 05:58:24 UTC)


How do you parse the time?

Comment: sleeps[1] is an array with these items
{"startTime"=>"2015-12-10T05:58:24.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-10T13:33:24.000Z"}
{"startTime"=>"2015-12-09T03:35:28.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-09T13:04:28.000Z"}  and then I get bed_times like this

bed_times = sleeps[1].map{|el| el['startTime']}.map{|el| Time.zone.parse(el.to_s) };

Comment: try to add .to_s at the end   .map{|el| Time.zone.parse(el.to_s).to_s }

Comment: Thank you.  One last thing.  The avg time 05:26 is in UTC.  I want to convert it to PST.  I tried Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'; Time.zone.parse(avg)
2015-12-11 05:26:57 -0800
It didn't seem to convert it to PST

Comment: @user2974739 I add the conversion from UTC to PST zone.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry Cary, I can't follow you. I've read your answer just now.

Comment: Nick, sorry, I meant to post my comment on the question.  I deleted my comment and will also delete this one when I figure you've seen it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are given an array `arr` that contains the UTC times of bedtimes in areas that are on PST time. You wish to compute the average bedtime.

**Code**

```
def avg_bedtime(arr)
  avg = Time.at(arr.reduce(0) do |t,s|
    lt = Time.parse(s).localtime("-08:00")
    t + Time.new(2000, 1, (lt.hour < 12) ? 2 : 1, lt.hour, lt.min, lt.sec, "-08:00").to_f
  end/arr.size)
  "%d:%d:%d" % [avg.hour, avg.min, avg.sec]
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = ["2015-12-10 08:58:24 UTC", "2015-12-09 03:35:28 UTC",
       "2015-12-08 06:32:26 UTC", "2015-12-07 01:43:28 UTC",
       "2015-12-05 07:49:30 UTC", "2015-12-04 07:02:30 UTC"]
```

I've changed the first time in this array to make it more interesting.

```
avg_bedtime(arr)
  #=> "21:56:57"
```

**Explanation**

Let's begin by converting these strings to time objects:

```
utc = arr.map { |s| Time.parse(s) }
  #=> [2015-12-10 08:58:24 UTC, 2015-12-09 03:35:28 UTC, 2015-12-08 06:32:26 UTC,
  #    2015-12-07 01:43:28 UTC, 2015-12-05 07:49:30 UTC, 2015-12-04 07:02:30 UTC]
```

Recalling that PST is 8 hours later than UTC, we can use [Time.localtime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-localtime) to convert to PST:

```
pst = utc.map { |t| t.localtime("-08:00") }
  #=> [2015-12-10 00:58:24 -0800, 2015-12-08 19:35:28 -0800,
  #    2015-12-07 22:32:26 -0800, 2015-12-06 17:43:28 -0800,
  #    2015-12-04 23:49:30 -0800, 2015-12-03 23:02:30 -0800]
```

I will refer to bedtimes before noon to be "late" bedtimes and those later in the day to be "early" bedtimes. (This is of course arbitrary. If, for example, some of the individuals are shift workers, this could be a problem.) As you see, the first element of `pst` is a late bedtime and all others are early bedtimes.

I will now convert these time objects to time objects having the same time of day but a different date. Early bedtime objects will be assigned an arbitrary date (say, `January 1, 2000`) and late bedtime objects will be one day later (`January 2, 2000`):

```
adj = pst.map { |t| Time.new(2000, 1, (t.hour < 12) ? 2 : 1, t.hour, t.min, t.sec, "-08:00") }
  #=> [2000-01-02 00:58:24 -0800, 2000-01-01 19:35:28 -0800, 2000-01-01 22:32:26 -0800,
 #     2000-01-01 17:43:28 -0800, 2000-01-01 23:49:30 -0800, 2000-01-01 23:02:30 -0800]
```

We can now convert the time objects to seconds since the epoch:

```
secs = adj.map { |t| t.to_f }
  #=> [946803504.0, 946784128.0, 946794746.0, 946777408.0, 946799370.0, 946796550.0]
```

compute the average:

```
avg = secs.reduce(:+)/arr.size
  #=> 946792617.6666666
```

convert back to a time object for the PST zone:

```
tavg = Time.at(avg)
  #=> 2000-01-01 21:56:57 -0800
```

and, lastly, extract the time of day:

```
"%d:%d:%d" % [tavg.hour, tavg.min, tavg.sec]
  # "21:56:57
```